# what is the usage of extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

can some one explain me what is the usage of extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. If Ido not extend also ResponseEntityExceptionHandler GlobalExceptionHandler is working and sending the response to client.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class, ContentNotAllowedException.class })
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        if (ex instanceof UserNotFoundException) {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
            UserNotFoundException unfe = (UserNotFoundException) ex;

            return handleUserNotFoundException(unfe, headers, status, request);
        } else if (ex instanceof ContentNotAllowedException) {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
            ContentNotAllowedException cnae = (ContentNotAllowedException) ex;

            return handleContentNotAllowedException(cnae, headers, status, request);
        } else {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, headers, status, request);
        }
    }

}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class, ContentNotAllowedException.class })
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        if (ex instanceof UserNotFoundException) {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
            UserNotFoundException unfe = (UserNotFoundException) ex;

            return handleUserNotFoundException(unfe, headers, status, request);
        } else if (ex instanceof ContentNotAllowedException) {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
            ContentNotAllowedException cnae = (ContentNotAllowedException) ex;

            return handleContentNotAllowedException(cnae, headers, status, request);
        } else {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, headers, status, request);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is used when one is generally satisfied with Spring's default ExceptionHandlers - except for a few, which may then be overridden.

Have a look at all the protected methods in the API documentation:

- [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html)

Your `GlobalExceptionHandler` is already accepting any Exceptions and custom handling two specific Exceptions.

If you insist on using `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, a similar effect may be achieved by extending the class and implementing `handleExceptionInternal()`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public handleExceptionInternal() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ResponseEntityExceptionHandler encapsulates the handling of various exceptions that may be thrown by Spring MVC during request processing.

By inheriting this class, one can override the corresponding handling logic.

If you inherit ResponseEntityExceptionHandler to handle exceptions, then the default exception response is empty. If you want it to be non-empty, you’ll need to handle it yourself (Add your own body).

For example：

```java
return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getResponse().getStatus())
                .body(new ApiErrorResponse(ex.getResponse().getStatus(),
                                           ex.getResponse().getMessage(),
                                           ex.getResponse().getErrors()));
```

```java
body.put(....);
return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
```